# Calculating number of trials until success?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

Consider the following problems:

> On average, a button can be pressed 20 times before it fails to operate. What is the probability that it is pressed 35 times before it fails (36 times total)?
>
> Suppose we wire three buttons together...now what is the probability we would be able to perform 36 total presses?

I was thinking geometric distribution was the solution. $(1-\frac{1}{20})^{35}*\frac{19}{20}=0.1578$.

I don't know if geometric distribution is even the correct method or if I used the right numbers, as this seems like a high probability considering the button typically fails at $20$.

What is the proper way to solve these problems?

Comment: You *must* start by making assumptions, for otherwise a huge range of answers can be justified. For instance, maybe the button has a tendency either to fail at once (in 50% of all cases) and otherwise is certain to last for 40 pushes and then fail. This button would meet all the conditions of the question--and the chance that you could make 36 pushes obviously would be $1/2$. In another case the button might last between 10 and 30 pushes (with an average of 20), in which case the chance of 35 pushes would be zero.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your arithmetic!  If you model it as a geometric, the probability is indeed 15.8% for any individual button - almost 60% for 3 in parallel assuming all 3 are pushed each of the 36 times...

However, as @whuber pointed out, your initial assumptions can put the 16% up to 50% or down to 0%.

For better or worse, geometric/exponential is what many people assume when they combine mean time between failures to estimate product lifetimes from their individual components.  If this is more than an academic exercise, you might consider something in the Weibull family of distributions instead of geometric.  Or better yet, take data on the system and estimate the real distribution!